# Spacemacs/org-mode/visual line bug

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I'm using `org-mode` and `visual-line-mode` with Spacemacs by pressing `<SPC> t l`.  However, when I do this I get strange behavior, possibly due to the visual indenting of lines.  As I move between lines, the cursor seems to jump all over the place.  I've recorded a short video of it that you can see below. You can see as I move down (`j`) the lines, especially from the first row of a paragraph to the second, the cursor jumps. Also, as I move up (`k`), occasionally the cursor will skip a line.  How do I make these two modes play nice with each other?

https://gfycat.com/SpicyGiganticAmazontreeboa

Comment: If you think you see behavior that is a bug, report it to the package maintainers.

Comment: @Drew I certainly will if it is a bug, but I figured I'd ask here to see if I'm doing something wrong, and if it's not a bug, correct it.